Groovy "spaceship operator" when sorting lists-of-lists
If I have a list-of-lists, then .sort() works naturally; i.e., element-wise:
groovy:000> [[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[1,2,2]].sort()                      
===> [[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

However, if I write an explicit sort closure, using the <=> operator, it fails:
groovy:000> [[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[1,2,2]].sort { a, b -> a <=> b }
ERROR java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[3, 1, 2]' and java.util.ArrayList with value '[3, 2, 1]'
        at groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1.doCall (groovysh_evaluate:3)

In this toy case, it doesn't matter, but I have a more complicated structure that requires me to use a sort closure. I understand that <=>, per the documentation, is syntactic sugar for .compareTo, which java.util.ArrayList values don't have. However, how does the "bare sort" get around this problem?
The reason I ask is because I found a solution, but it feels a bit cludgy:
listOfLists.sort { a, b -> new Tuple(*a) <=> new Tuple(*b) }

I wonder if there's a more idiomatic solution that effectively does the same as the bare sort?

Isn't sort{ a, b -> a <=> b } the same as just sort()?

Apparently not, as the output in my question demonstrates.

I mean the result is the same for the example given.

In the example given, sort { a, b -> a <=> b } raises an exception when the elements are lists, so in this case their outputs are definitely not the same. That's ultimately the core of my question: Groovy must be doing something special with just sort(), rather than simply { a, b -> a <=> b }.

<=> is an overloaded operator for Comparable.compareTo; therefor the
LHS must implement this method and List does not, hence the error.
When using just [].sort(), then groovy uses NumberAwareComparator,
which tries to use
DefaultTypeTransformation.compareTo,
which again expects the LHS to be
a Comparable
(or a Number, but we can ignore this here).  Since the LHS is not
a Comparable, this method throws and NumberAwareComparator falls
back to comparing the hash
codes
of both sides.
Whether to trust this behaviour is a different story.  Wrapping the
comparison in a container, that can compareTo (like Tuple) feels way
safer (e.g. it properly short-circuits)

Interesting! So it could just be luck that the hash of my internal lists just happen to have the correct ordering properties. Thanks for the explanation :) I'll stick with Tuple(*x)!
